# Is this an undesirable grass or a weed?

Tags: weed-control, grass, weeds, lawn

I have some patchy weird grass or weeds growing on my lawn. You can see in a few places in the images below:

Picture 1: you can see the longer wider grass blades scattered here. What is this? A broadleaf weed or a grass that I just don't want? How do I get rid of it?
[image: weird grass 1]

Picture 2: it looks like I have some fine fescue (right?) with some similar wide blade grass/weeds? How do I get rid of the larger grass/weeds? It's ugly and undesirable.
[image: weird grass 2]

Picture 3: you can see it a bit better here. I think my desirable lawn here is a bit of fine fescue and maybe some KBG (the slightly discolored + green blades at the bottom of the picture?). Does that seem right? What about that nasty ugly clump near the top of the picture? Broadleaf weed or undesirable grass? Is it the same as pictures 1 + 2? I think so. How do I get rid of these?
[image: weird grass 3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be some sort of rougher grass type that can often be found in rural areas (pastures, mountainside fields and the like). The good thing is they do clump together, so you have 2 options to take them out:

- Dig out the clump of grass, then refill with black soil
- Use weed killer to kill off all the grass in an area

Then simply reseed with the grass-seed of choice.
Personally I would go for option 1, as it is a lot less destructive (to the environment and the grass around it), and it has the bonus of being faster and cheaper (instead of having to wait for the grass to die, having to dig up a huge patch etc.)